# python requests not responding to this code in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-colaboratory

```
import requests  
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050"  
headers = { "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36",  
       "Accept-Language" : "en-US;q=0.5",  
       "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate"}  

js = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()  
r = js['data']  
print(r)
```

this code works fine in pycharm but not working in colab ... please help how to get rid of this

i just need to get this `json` data in Colab

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    376             try:  # Python 2.7, use buffering of HTTP responses
--> 377                 httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
    378             except TypeError:  # Python 3

TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: /usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    629         """
    630         if buffer is not None:
--> 631             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    632         else:
    633             v = self._sslobj.read(len)

Comment: same question. any answers?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible. As Colab uses hosted runtime and this request will be rejected by the NSE to avoid Dos(Denial of service) attack.